# Problem with Fortran substring comparison of different length

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am reading stdin in a loop and do some comparaison with a bunch of "if" to decide what to do according to the input.

Here is a shortened snippet of the code :

```
CHARACTER (len= :), allocatable :: input
CHARACTER (len=4096) :: inbuffer            ! frustrating but... well, fortran :3

DO

    ! get input
    READ(*, '(a)') inbuffer     ! because apparently you can't have allocation on read so you can't just read "input". meh.
    input = TRIM(inbuffer)
    CALL debug_log(input)

    IF(input .EQ. 'uci') THEN
        CALL debug_log("   printing uci info")

    !isready
    ELSE IF(input .EQ. 'isready') THEN
        CALL debug_log("   isready -> readyok")
        WRITE(*, '(a)') "readyok"

    !ucinewgame
    ELSE IF(input .EQ. 'ucinewgame') THEN
        CALL debug_log("not implemented : reset board and start a new game")

    !position
    ELSE IF(input(1:8) .EQ. 'position') THEN
        CALL debug_log("not implemented : set position")

    !quit -> exit main loop
    ELSE IF(input .EQ. 'quit') THEN
        CALL debug_log("   quit command issued, exiting main loop")
        EXIT

    !non uci command
        !nothing yet

    !unknown command
    ELSE
        CALL debug_log("   ignoring invalid command")
    END IF

end do
```

The input will expect command like "position 123 23415 etc..."

If I type "posi" it's say it's an invalid command as expected.

If I type "position" it say it's not implemented as expected too.

**However**:

- If I type "position": I get not implemented
- Followed by "posi": it says "not implemented" instead of "invalid command"

My guess is that it read 8 character even if the input is only 4 and since the previous command was "position" it make posi + tion = position

Here is some log to demonstrate:

```
** opening debug file : 20181111 / 223418.127
223418.127 : Initializing Fortiche engine
223418.129 : Entering main loop
223420.859 : posi
223420.859 :    ignoring invalid command
223426.467 : xxxxtion
223426.467 :    ignoring invalid command
223430.498 : posi
223430.498 : not implemented : set position
223437.323 : xxxxxxxxx
223437.323 :    ignoring invalid command
223439.418 : posi
223439.418 :    ignoring invalid command
223443.979 : position
223443.979 : not implemented : set position
223447.122 : quit
223447.122 :    quit command issued, exiting main loop
223447.122 : closing, bye
```

xxxxtion + posi = position

Which is clearly wrong but I can understand how it ended up like this.

Should I use something other than .EQ.?
When I print the input it clearly doesn't print the input + whatever garbage was left behind in memory. But it's doing it when comparing string of possibly different length.

What can I do to solve this problem?

I'm not even started with the hardcore parsing and I already have a problem.

I'm using GNU Fortran on Windows.

Yes, it's UCI stuff as Universal Chess Interface.

EDIT : Full source code : https://github.com/ker2x/fortiche (comment the dirty hack at line 107 & 108 to reproduce the problem)

Comment: It would be good to have a compilable mcve we could try ourselves. This stuff should work and it is not *that* hard. I wrote a simple Scheme interpretter in Fortran, even parsing can be done. Please try to use capital letters when writing questions and answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substring references need to have starting and ending positions that are within the limits of the string.

You don't defend against a string that has a length less than eight prior to the substring reference `input(1:8) .eq. 'position'`.

With input shorter than eight characters, your program is non-conforming, anything can then happen, where anything very reasonably includes the behaviour you see.

Runtime debugging options may help to catch this programming error, depending on the capabilities of your compiler.

Comment: Oh, missed the TRIM duing my quick look. Here a compilable code would definitely help.

Comment: @VladimirF i edited my post with a link to the full compilable source code https://github.com/ker2x/fortiche

Comment: i added stuff at line 107 and 108 to temporary solve the problem but it's a dirty hack. comment them to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ker2x I cant get anywhere with that link, but it does not matter. You have the answer from IanH and that should be enough.

Comment: So what should i do in practice ? Check if the input length is "at least" 8 characters before comparing it with a 8 character string ?

Comment: The comparison is not the issue, it is the substring. What's best depends on what you want to do, but consider something like `input(1:min(len(input),8))`, which you might factor out into its own function.

Comment: Two notes/recommendations: Fortran's `trim()` function is more properly `rtrim()` in any other language (trims trailing spaces only). `adjustl()` shifts the string left which appends leading spaces to the end of the string so it's the same length as the original; `trim(adjustl(inbuffer))` implements a proper `trim` function, removing both leading and trailing spaces. Similarly, you can use `len_trim(audjustl(inbuffer))` to get the length of the (properly) trimmed string. Second, consider using Fortran's `select/case` construct instead of cascaded `if/then/elseif` for clarity.

Comment: i wanted to do a switch/case but after some research it seems you can't simply do a case "mystring" so it doesn't really help. And the snippet doesn't show it but i'll need a bunch of nested "if" because i'm not parsing a single world but, potentially, a bunch of commands on a single line. i'm using this https://github.com/jeffreyan11/uci-chess-engine/blob/master/src/uci.cpp as a reference for the uci parser. 

it may be a personnal opinion, not sure, but multiple nested switch/case are much worse in readability than a bunch of if/else.

Comment: @VladimirF the repo was private, sorry about this. it's now public